# Angular Directive Different Template

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have a directive myDirective with variable type. If I run `<my-directive type="X">` I want the directive to use templateUrl: x-template.html. 
If I do `<my-directive type="Y">` I want the directive to use templateUrl: y-template.html.

This is my current directive.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    var myDirective = {
        templateUrl: 'X-template.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            type: '=' 
        },
    };
    return myDirective;
});
```

I read thru stackoverflow and angular documentation but have not found anything that I need.

I am now trying to do something along the lines of:

```
if ($scope.type === 'X') {
    templateUrl: 'X-template.html',
}
else if ($scope.type === 'Y') {
    templateUrl: 'Y-template.html',
}
```

But do not know where to do it.

Do you guys know if this is possible and how?

Comment: Post the directive please.

Comment: Maybe try `type: '&'` instead of `type: '='`, and `templateURL: '{{type}}-template.html',`. Its a long shot and I haven't tested it, I'm just speculating. Also, state your `templateURL` after your scope statement. Don't know if you need too, it just makes me feel all warm inside...

Comment: Also, can you post your HTML implementation of this directive?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can work around [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1039) using `ng-include` inside `compile`:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            element.append('<div ng-include="\'' + attrs.type + '-template.html\'"></div>');
        }
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/LuvXk/)

Comment: @MarkRajcok How can i pass value to the templates ? suppose if i want to set attribute name="something" and pass this values in template ??

Answer (score 103):

Angular will accept a function as the template option, so you could do something like so:

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
            if (tAttrs) {
                if (tAttrs.type === 'X') {
                    return 'X-template.html';
                }
                if (tAttrs.type === 'Y') {
                    return 'Y-template.html';
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

For more info, see the documentation for the [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service.

Comment: This is the most succinct answer, should be the accepted one.

Comment: Thanks. This does it.

Answer (score 7):

If you're willing to live on the bleeding edge with a build on the 1.1.x code path (note the warning attached to every 1.1.x build notes entry so I don't dilute this answer by repeating it again here), you're in luck--this very feature was just added in the 1.1.4 release on April 3rd.  You can find the release notes for 1.1.4 [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and the feature's [task log](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/eb53423a41136fcda0c5e711f2d104952080354b) includes a Jasmine test that demonstrates how to use the new functionality.

If you're more conservative and are using a 1.0.x release, then you won't be able to accomplish this as easily, but it can be done.  Mark Rajcok's solution looks like it would fit your requirements as-stated, but I would just add a few additional notes:

- Aside from its 1.1.4 release, compile-time directives don't support modification at runtime.

  - As of 1.1.4, you can [safely modify the attributes of compile-time directives](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/fe8d893b839e9b14e3e55a3a0523cc1e6355bdd5), but only from another compile-time directive.
- You may want to consider `replaceWith()` instead of `append()` since `<my-directive>` is not a standard-defined HTML element type.
- If your X and Y templates contain additional directives, I don't think you'll be able to pass attributes on `<my-template>` through to the root element of your template so easily.

  - A directive with replace: true will transfer attributes from the source element to its replacement root, but I do not think that `ngInclude` will do the same from is host  to the root of the included template.
  - I also seem to recall that `ngInclude` does not require that its template have exactly one root element.
  - You could perhaps preserve attributes on a replacement parent by using `replaceWith()` instead of `append()` and wrapping the `<div ng-include="">` tag within a `<div></div>`.  The outer `<div>` could hold attributes and would still be accessible after the `<div ngInclude>` element replaced itself with loaded content.
- Be aware that `ngInclude` creates a new scope.  This subjects you to a flashing yellow klaxons warning about the dangers of primitive scope models.  For more information, see [this fine page from Angular's GitHub depot](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/The-Nuances-of-Scope-Prototypal-Inheritance).

I can propose another alternative for those on 1.0.x, but it involves a fair amount of code.  It's a more heavy-weight operation, but it has the upside of not only being able of switching between templates, but full-fledged directives as well.  Furthermore, its behavior is more readily dynamic.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'partials/directive/my-directive.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            // You can do this with isolated scope as well of course.
            scope.type = attrs.type;
        }
    }
);
```

my-directive.js

```
<div ng-switch on="{{type}}">
    <div ng-switch-where="X" ng-include="X-template.html"></div>
    <div ng-switch-where="Y" ng-include="Y-template.html"></div>
</div>
```

my-directive.html

Comment: I'd rather templateURL took an array instead!

Answer (score 5):

This is my version for optionally overriding a default template

```
templateUrl: function (elem, attrs) {
  if (attrs.customTemplate) {
    return '/path/to/components/tmpl/' + attrs.customTemplate + '.html';
  } else {
    return '/path/to/components/tmpl/directive.html';
  }
}
```

e.g on a directive

```
<div my-directive custom-template="custom"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I solve this problem so:

```
app.directive("post", function ($templateCache, $compile) {
function getTemplate(mode) {
    switch (mode) {
        case "create":
            return "createPost.html";
        case "view":
            return "viewPost.html";
        case "delete":
            return "deletePost.html";
    }
}

var defaultMode = "view";

return {
    scope: {},
    restrict: "AE",
    compile: function (elem, attrs, transclude) {
        return function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
            function updateTemplate() {
                $element.html("");
                $compile($templateCache.get(getTemplate($scope.mode)).trim())($scope, function (clonedElement, scope) {
                    clonedElement.appendTo($element);

                });
            }

            $scope.mode = $attr.mode || defaultMode;

            $scope.$watch("mode", updateTemplate);
        }
    }
}
});
```

It's probably not the best way to do this, but I have no extra scope.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, this might help someone here :-)

To inject your custom attr into your link or controller function use the following.

I'm at work right now but will post a fiddle later if I get a chance :-)

```
.directive('yourDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: '<div></div>', // or use templateUrl with/without function
    scope: {
      myAttibute: '@myAttr' // adds myAttribute to the scope
    },
    link: function(scope) {
      console.log(scope.myAttibute);
    }
  }
}
```

// HTML ""

// Console will output "foo"