# Use a condition in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in someArray"></div>
```

I would like to use the custom directive "type1" if `obj.type == "type1"` and use the custom directive "type2" if `obj.type == "type2"`. Is there a smart way to do that?

### Edit

I will use this solution at different locations, so I would like to put the logic in the directive and not in the html. I was thinking that maybe I could use a "parent" directive that "includes" one directive or the other depending on `obj.type`. What do you think?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666307/angularjs-if-statements

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164371/inline-conditionals-in-angular-js/14165488#14165488

Comment: I've edited my question for more precisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't attribute a function to `templateUrl` in the current stable version (1.0.8), so here is what I did.

### HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="genericDirective" ng-repeat="obj in someArray"></div>
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.someArray = [
        {type:"type1",title:"lorem"},
        {type:"type2",title:"ipsum"},
        {type:"type2",title:"dolor"}
    ];
});

app.directive("genericDirective", function(){
    return{
        restrict: "C",
        templateUrl: "genericDirective.html" 
    };
});
```

### genericDirective.html

```
<div ng-include="thumb.type+'Thumb.html'"></div>
```

For some reason, I did not manage to nest directives, so I used `ng-include` instead. (**Edit**: Problem solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132866/nested-directives-dont-work-as-expected))

Answer (score 6):

Use [ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch):

```
   <div ng-repeat="obj in someArray">
     <span ng-switch="obj.type">
      <div directive-one ng-switch-when="type1"></div>
      <div directive-two ng-switch-when="type2"></div>
     </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: I suppose you could do that, but I was looking for a solution that doesn't add too many div/span

Comment: I've answered my question if you are interested

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want, you can use ngClass for this.

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in someArray">
  <div ng-class"{class1: obj.type == "type1", class2: obj.type == "type2"}"></div>
</div>
```

In this example, the object's type would apply a class.
See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass for more information.

If this is to parse the data or something similar, you can try to use one directive, and handle the case inside.

Edit:

To expand on the later, you can put your logic in a service and call the appropriate functions in a parent directive.  http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services

Comment: I've edited my answer with more markup.  I've also expanded on how to do the parent directive if you wanted to take that path.

Comment: I've answered my question if you are interested

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in someArray">
    <type1 ng-if="obj.type=='type1'"></type1>
    <type2 ng-if="obj.type=='type2'"></type2>
</div>
```

In angular 1.2 you can use the ng-switch directive as well which is more efficient.

I guess I should add that the test might look more like this

```
ng-if="obj instanceof type1"
```

depending on what you mean by type.

Based on further comments I believe that this is also a possible answer to your question:

[Angular Directive Different Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490382/angular-directive-different-template)

Still, ng-if or ng-switch is a much easier way since it doesn't require any special knowledge of the ng-repeat object type.

Comment: I was looking for a solution that doesn't require too much logic html-side. Sorry I should have been more precise

Comment: Where do you want to specify the logic for inclusion?

Comment: The directive itself might be the best place.  By specifying a different template inside of the directive depending on the obj.type might be a good approach.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but is it possible to have two "template" or "templateUrl"

Comment: Yes, If you test for the type in the link function you can specify whatever you want as the template.  Maybe show a pretend piece of what you think the HTML markup should look like.

Comment: I'm not at work right now, I will try your solution and/or give more precisions tomorrow. Thanks for your help

Comment: It can be done but it is moving beyond my knowledge of angular. Don't mark an answer as correct and maybe someone will see it and tell you how.

Comment: I've answered my question if you are interested