# How to have template based on object type in javascript, using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop

I have some objects, each one has a property which shows their type, something like this:

```
[
    {
        "type" : "date",
        ...
    },{
        "type" : "phone",
        ...
    },{
        "type" : "boolean",
        ...
    }
]
```

I want to have something which shows them in their proper templates, which may differ in DOM,(for example one just has a span, the other has a check box and an input text and so on). I want to do this in a generic manner. How can I do this? (I use angular, if it helps)

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16491616/63011

Comment: @PaoloMoretti That's what I want, make it an answer to let me accept it

Answer (score 0):

I would create a directive that takes an object as a scoped variable and renders it as needed in the linked function.

```
<mydirective data='{ "type" : "date"}'>
```