# AngularJS - Compile with ng-include bypasses internal controller in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'd like to have a directive with multiple templates as in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16491616/2929757)

When using compile in a directive as in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/LuvXk/) 
the the ng-include uses the external controller and the 
and the internal controller is not available to the scope of the template

example

```
function someDirective(){
return {
scope:{
  ...
},

compile: function(element, attrs) {
  var type = "extended"; //default
  if(typeof attrs.type !== 'undefined')
    type = attrs.type;
  element.append('<div ng-include="\'myproj/views/templates/group/groups-' + type + '.html\'"></div>');
},
//templateUrl: 'myproj/views/templates/group/groups-sideMenu.html',
controller:function($scope, $attrs, $rootScope, UtilsSrvc){
  // ... the template won't use this controller  
 }
 }
 }
```

how to fix this problem?

**EDIT**

After some headbang something got clearer
[In this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LuvXk/103/) (by Alessandro Cifani) the script works either for Angular 1.0, Angular 1.1 and Angular 1.2

The problems start when trying to isolate the scope: 
[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccuhejwe/) only works with Angular <= 1.1, with Angular >= 1.2 is not working

Things change when an empty 'templateUrl' is added as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1bz59qp8/): it starts to be compliant to all versions

???????????????

Answer (score 1):

I would use a different approach:

1) yoy may use the `$compile` service

2) you should avoid to use `ng-include` in favor of custom directives.

Following an example of what I'm saying:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myApp', [])

  .directive('user',
    function user($compile, $window) {
      return {
        scope: {
          role: '@',
          name: '@'
        },
        restrict: 'EA',

        link: function link(scope, elem) {

          var roles = {
            SUPERADMIN: '<button ng-click="doSomething()" class="btn">Do something</button>',
            STUDENT: '<div class="alert alert-success">You are a student</div>',
            OTHER: '<div>Guest users have no options</div>'
          };

          // Create HTML elements in according with the role (SUPERADMIN, STUDENT, OTHER)
          var role = roles[scope.role] || roles.OTHER;
          var html = '<div><h2>' + scope.name + '</h2>' + role + '</div>';

          // Step 1: parse HTML into DOM element
          var template = angular.element(html);
          //console.log (html);

          // Step 2: compile the template
          var linkFn = $compile(template);
          //console.log (linkFn);

          // Step 3: link the compiled template with the scope.
          var element = linkFn(scope);
          console.log (element[0]);

          // Step 4: Append to DOM (optional)
          elem.append(element);

          scope.doSomething = function doSomething() {
            $window.alert('doSomething');
          };

        }
      };
    }
  );

})();
```

USAGE:

```
<user name="fabio" role="SUPERADMIN"></user>
<user name="paolo" role="STUDENT"></user>
<user name="marco"></user>
```

NOTE: in the previous example you could replace my "SUPERADMIN", "STUDENT" and "OTHER" templates with your own custom directives, ie: , ,

and here a JSBin: https://jsbin.com/mumahobuwu/edit?html,js,output